# script/code to find a file in the entire file system + install4j

Tags: java, install4j

I have a requirement to find a file(file**.exe) in the entire file system and get the path of it. I searched in the available code gallery and did not find anything similar to the requirement. 
Can I add custom java method in the script section?May be implementing something similar to the recursive search. If yes, how to add custom method in the 'run a script' action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add methods in scripts, but you can add methods in the static code (Custom code & Resources -> Edit code). Methods defined in static code can be used in all scripts.